# Find multiple arguments in getopt command Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, getopt

I need the script to look into the arguments given in command line and give an error output if two specific arguments are given in the same command line.

Please note that parameters b & c are mutually exclusive.

I need to have a way that if in the command line both -b & -c is given, the system will provide an error message and exit. Also if there any other way to write the code?

Thanks, NH

My sample code is like this:

```
import getopt

def main():
    x = ''

    try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "habc",["help","Task_a", "Task_b", "Task_c"])
    except getopt.GetoptError:
            print("Wrong Parameter")
            sys.exit()
    for opt, args in opts:
        if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
            x = "h"

        elif opt in ("-a", "--Task_a"):
            x= "a"

        elif opt in ("-b", "--Task_b"):
            x = "b"

        elif opt in ("-c", "--Task_c"):
            x = "c"

        else:
            x = "something Else"

    return x 
if __name__ =="main":
    main()
print(main())
```

Comment: Why not set a simple counter that increments when either -b or -c is entered and then test if the value is greater than 1 and display error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module that support [mutual exclusion](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion).

To answer your question, you could use this simple logic

```
optnames = [opt[0] for opt in opts]
if (("-b" in optnames or "--Task-b" in optnames) and
        ("-c" in optnames or "--Task-c" in optnames)):
    print("-b and -c are mutually exclusive", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. I could not make it work. for testing purpose I put it in this code:   `import getopt
import sys  

opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "habc",["help","Task_a", "Task_b", "Task_c"])  

if ("-b", "--Task_b") in opts and ("-c", "--Task_c") in opts:  
    print("-b and -c are mutually exclusive", file=sys.stderr)  
    sys.exit()  
else:  
    print("Arguments are OK")`

Comment: Apparently I gave you wrong condition. I updated the answer now. This WILL work

Comment: Thanks you Shiplu. This is actually what I was looking for. It works nicely.

Comment: Done. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) for that.

Here's a simple example to make it work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Doing some tasks')
parser.add_argument('-b', action='store_true', help="Proceed to task B")
parser.add_argument('-c', action='store_true', help="Proceed to task C")

args = parser.parse_args('-b -c'.split())

if args.b and args.c:
   sys.exit()

if args.b:
    # do something
if args.c:
    # do something else
```

**EDIT**:
You can also use a mutually exclusive group. Thanks for suggesting [shiplu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376535/shiplu-mokadd-im).

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Doing some tasks')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-b', action='store_true', help="Proceed to task B")
group.add_argument('-c', action='store_true', help="Proceed to task C")
```

And then when you try to enter both of the arguments:

```
In [80]: args=parser.parse_args('-b -c'.split())
usage: ipython [-h] [-b | -c]
ipython: error: argument -c: not allowed with argument -b
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

Otherwise,

```
In [82]: parser.parse_args('-b'.split())
Out[82]: Namespace(b=True, c=False)

In [83]: parser.parse_args('-c'.split())
Out[83]: Namespace(b=False, c=True)
```

Comment: If you use argparse why not use `add_mutually_exclusive_group` ?

Comment: Thanks elena for your solution. I was not familiar with argparse so I did not use it, but now I can see how easy it can be to use in this situation. Great job !!